# How I assert the ordered list descending in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a problem when trying to assert some results related to the ordered list (descending). The result is the created_at and the value is the date format.

Here is some example:

```
${created_at}= "2022-02-28", "2022-02-27", "2022-02-26", "2022-02-25"
```

I need to verify that the created_at should be the newest.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean you want to verify that `${created_at}` is sorted in descending order.

You basically need to copy `${created_at}` into a new list, then sort it and compare it to `${created_at}`. You can do it with python `sorted` or [Collections Libary](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.1.2/libraries/Collections.html)

Example:

```
Library           Collections

*** Variables ***
@{created_at}                       "2022-02-27"
...                                 "2022-02-25"
...                                 "2022-02-28"
...                                 "2022-02-26"

@{actual_list}                      "2022-02-28"    
...                                 "2022-02-27"
...                                 "2022-02-26"
...                                 "2022-02-25"
*** Test Cases ***
Test with Collections
    ${expected_list}=   Copy List       ${created_at}
    Sort List   ${expected_list}
    #descending
    Reverse List    ${expected_list}
    Lists Should Be Equal     ${expected_list}       ${actual_list}

Test With Python
    ${expected_list}=       Evaluate        sorted(${created_at}, reverse=True)
    Lists Should Be Equal     ${expected_list}       ${actual_list}
```

Comment: can you please give the complete script or code as an example?

Comment: Edited comment to add the code, please accept the answer if you find it useful